# Incorrect looping with nested loops

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm attempting to iterate through books on a website, it should only be getting 20 results before moving onto the next page.

i look at an element to get the total amount of pages (num_pages), this gives me the max number of pages which i can then iterate through.

The issue i have with the code is that the nest loop (locate anchor nodes) doesn't give just 20 urls from a single page, but loops over the same ones.

I'm not 100% where the nested loop is going wrong, so any pointers would be really helpful.

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)
print("Browsing to Wordery")
driver.get('https://wordery.com/search?viewBy=grid&resultsPerPage=20&page=1&leadTime[]=any&interestAge[]=Babies')
#print((driver.page_source).encode('utf-8'))
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#Get total pages
num_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="js-pnav-max"]')


#iterate through pages grabbing links
for i in range(int(num_page.text)):
    
    #locate anchor nodes
    lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='"'c-book__title'"']")
    links = []
    for lis in lists:
        
        # Fetch and store the links
        links.append(lis.get_attribute('href'))
        with open('search_results_urls.txt', 'a') as filehandle:
            filehandle.write('%s\n' % lis.get_attribute('href'))
            print(lis.get_attribute('href'))
    
    page_ = i + 1
    click_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="o-layout__item o-link--arrow js-pnav-next u-utils-pnav__next"]').click()

driver.quit()
```

Oddly it will loop through the first page 33 times (there are only 20 items and so it duplicates them) and then produces the below error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <a class="c-book__title" href="/peppa-pig-practise-with-peppa-wipe-clean-first-letters-peppa-pig-9780723292081"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

i've tested the below with removing the page navigation loop and it works as expected.

```
lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='c-book__title']")
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in lists]

with open('search_results_urls.txt', 'a') as filehandle:
    for link in links:
        filehandle.write(link)
        print(link)
```

As soon as i add this into the page loop, it ends up looping through the same page of urls.

This is now my latest code with input from the answer below. I'm still struggling with it looping over the first page multiple times.

```
#Get total pages
num_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="js-pnav-max"]')

for i in range(int(num_page.text)):
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='c-book__title']")
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in lists]
    
    with open('search_results_urls.txt', 'a') as filehandle:
        for link in links:
            filehandle.write(link + "\n")
            print(link + "\n")
    
    click_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="o-layout__item o-link--arrow js-pnav-next u-utils-pnav__next"]').click()
```

Comment: I'm also not sure the last example will work, as i'm not updating either lists or links from the new page once the click is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting same links because you have assigned it to outside the loop. when page gets refreshed you still have the earlier links in it.

place inside for loop.use `WebDriverWait()`  and wait for `presence_of_all_elements_located()` so that when click to next page this will sync while page gets refreshed.

```
num_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="js-pnav-max"]')
for i in range(int(num_page.text)):
    lists =WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='c-book__title']"))) 
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in lists]
    with open('search_results_urls.txt', 'a') as filehandle:
        for link in links:
            filehandle.write(link)
            print(link)

    click_next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="o-layout__item o-link--arrow js-pnav-next u-utils-pnav__next"]').click()
    #provide some delay to refreshed the page.
     time.sleep(2)
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: using that code i get a the following message 

Message: The element reference of <a class="c-book__title" href="/welcome-to-our-world-a-celebration-of-children-everywhere-moira-butterfield-9781788001373"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: looking into this more, oddly, it looks like it does pull 10 links from the second page but then errors with the above message

Comment: @Nathan : Poosibly element is not visible the moment it is retrieving. I haven't tested that since I have no editor to test the code. Try with `presence_of_all_elements_located()` instead of `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and let me know how this goes

Comment: @Nathan : You need to provide some delay as well after clicks on next button so that page can load.

Comment: I've just added my latest code as its still looping over the first page. The code is in my original answer.

Comment: its working now, i was originally using the wrong code for a sleep. thank you for your help